# Which is the best algorithm to "Estimate and Visualize 2d skeleton using Opencv" from the drawn contour

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

Which is the best algorithm to "Estimate and Visulize 2d skeleton using Opencv" from the drawn contour?

Is the Recursive Centroid algorithm the Best?
Any reference links or docs please provide.

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate what you mean by "2D skeleton" or "recursive centroid" because I'm not sure if I understand either of those terms.

Comment: These are sort of common image processing terms.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the goal you have in mind? What is your image of? What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

Without doing all of your homework, here are some hints:

1. You have only a contour - a boundary that seperates the inside and the outside. To determine a  skeleton you need a contiguous filled in object. A flood-fill algorithm will work.
2. The skeleton of an object is the object that remains after iterative erosion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two approaches come to mind at this moment:

Use the local ridge-values of the distance transform of the image - they should give a fast and visually intuitive (but rather imprecise) estimate of what the 2D-skeleton would look like.

Another is a center-line extraction, that initially finds Canny edges, draws a ray along the gradient direction from each edge pixel until it reaches an opposite edge, and marks the mid-point of that line segment. This gives a rough initial feasible solution of the problem. Following this, there are other methods like dense tensor voting etc. to get the 2D skeleton.