# What are The opencv function useful for 2d skeleton estimation(ofRecursive centroids)

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, opencv, evolutionary-algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best algorithm to “Estimate and Visulize 2d skeleton using Opencv” from the drawn contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979327/which-is-the-best-algorithm-to-estimate-and-visulize-2d-skeleton-using-opencv-f)

Opencv functions or stepts for 2d skeleton estimation

Comment: This is a duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979327/which-is-the-best-algorithm-to-estimate-and-visulize-2d-skeleton-using-opencv-f

Answer (score 0):

See http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html

I don't see anything for clustering/centroids, but you might try FindContours: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours .

It sounds like you want to do visualization analysis and this library is more suited to machine vision.

Comment: Actually 2d skeleton estimation is very common in machine vision. A common example is finding holes in objects, a routine QA check. A machine vision implementation of that check can be done by finding 2D skeletons; objects with holes have skeletons with loops.